# I blurred a div but I want to do that everything inside of it to be focused

Tags: html, css, blur

Anyway, I blurred a div via this code:

```
background: #FFFFFF;

-webkit-filter: blur(2px);
-moz-filter: blur(2px);
-o-filter: blur(2px);
-ms-filter: blur(2px);
filter: blur(2px);
opacity: 0.4;
```

But I want to put inside that blurred div some text, and the stays stays blur too after all, is there a way to cause the text itself only to not blur?

Comment: can you not z-index the text to be above the div so it's not affected by the blur?

Answer (score 2):

## No, but:

You *can* position another element *over* the blurred element in that case.

See: `z-index` for this, along with the `position:` attribute.

Important: the element cannot be inside the blurred element and just have a higher `z-index` only. It needs to be outside it, positioned over the other one, *and* have a higher `z-index` than the blurred element.

Here is a *very* basic example, using `position: absolute;`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/ky3Ca/3/

**Excerpt:**

```
.unblurred {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

There are a lot of ways to do positioning. The above jsfiddle only shows one way to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can position the text over the div using some other html element, check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7PxzL/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
<span>This is the Text</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: #cccccc;
    z-index:-1px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
    -ms-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
}

span {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```